# MyApphow to check for "typeof MyApp.User.current.language"

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [javascript test for existence of nested object key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631001/javascript-test-for-existence-of-nested-object-key)

```
if (typeof MyApp != 'undefined' &&
    typeof MyApp.User != 'undefined' &&
    typeof MyApp.User.current != 'undefined' &&
    typeof MyApp.User.current.language != 'undefined') {

   console.log(MyApp.User.current.language);
}
```

this feels wrong. Can this if statement be written in some nicer way?

Comment: Where did that `Siag` come from?

Comment: thanks richard. fixed. was a c&p bug.

Answer (score 1):

One simple way is this:

```
try {
    console.log(MyApp.User.current.language);
} catch(e) {}
```

or if you don't want "undefined" to be output if `MyApp.User.current` exists, but `MyApp.User.current.language` does not, then you would use this:

```
try {
    if (typeof MyApp.User.current.language != 'undefined') {
        console.log(MyApp.User.current.language);
    }
} catch(e) {}
```

The `try/catch` catches the cases for when `MyApp` or `MyApp.user` or `MyApp.User.current` are not defined so you don't have to test for them individually.

Answer (score 1):

You could perform a [decompose conditional](http://refactoring.com/catalog/decomposeConditional.html) refactoring and put that condition in a function:

```
if (currentLanguageIsDefined()) {
   console.log(MyApp.User.current.language);
}

function currentLanguageIsDefined() {
    return typeof MyApp != 'undefined' &&
           typeof MyApp.User != 'undefined' &&
           typeof MyApp.User.current != 'undefined' &&
           typeof MyApp.User.current.language != 'undefined';
}
```

... or you can take advantage of the fact that the `&&` operator returns the last value evaluated:

```
var lang;
if(lang = getCurrentLang()) {
    console.log(lang);
}

function getCurrentLang() {
    return MyApp && MyApp.User && MyApp.User.current && MyApp.User.current.language;
}
```